# Minimum number of element required to make a sequence that sums to a particular number

Tags: math

Suppose there is number s=12 , now i want to make sequence with the element a1+a2+.....+an=12.

> The criteria  is as follows-
>
> 1. n must be minimum.
> 2. a1 and an must be 1;
> 3. ai can differs a(i-1) by only 1,0 and -1.

for s=12 the result is 6.

So how to find the minimum value of n.

Comment: This is a more of a math problem than programming.

Comment: If `s` is between `q^2+1` and `q^2+q`, you have minimum `n=2q`.  If `s` is between `q^2+q+1` and `(q+1)^2`, you have minimum `n=2q+1`.

Comment: Are you sure you need 6 elements to get 12? I can get it in 5: `1 2 2 3 4`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: jpalecek: `an` must be 1. I expect the optimal sequence is then `1 2 3 3 2 1`.

Comment: @jpalecek  yea, you have missed one thing a1 and an must be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algorithm for finding `n` from given `s`:

**1**.Find `q = FLOOR( SQRT(s-1) )`

**2**.Find `r = q^2 + q`

**3**.If `s <= r` then `n = 2q`, else `n = 2q + 1`

---

Example: `s = 12`

1. `q = FLOOR( SQRT(12-1) ) = FLOOR(SQRT(11) = 3`
2. `r = 3^2 + 3 = 12`
3. `12 <= 12`, therefore `n = 2*3 = 6`

Example: `s = 160`

1. `q = FLOOR( SQRT(160-1) ) = FLOOR(SQRT(159) = 12`
2. `r = 12^2 + 12 = 156`
3. `159 > 156`, therefore `n = 2*12 + 1 = 25`

and the 25-numbers sequence for

```
159:    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,9,10,10,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to visualize the solution.

First, draw the smallest triangle (rows containing successful odd numbers of stars) that has a greater or equal number of stars to n. In this case, we draw a 16-star triangle.

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Then we have to remove `16 - 12 = 4` more stars. We do this diagonally starting from the top.

```
   1
  **2
 ****3
******4
```

The result is:

```
  **
 ****
******
```

Finally, add up the column heights to get the final answer:

`1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1`.

Comment: Good visuals but I don't think you want to use this method if s = 123452. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum possible for any given series of length n is:

n is even => (n^2+2n)/4
n is odd  => (n+1)^2/4

These two results are arrived at easily enough by looking at the simple arithmetic sum of series where in the case of n even it is twice the sum of the series 1...n/2. In the case of n odd it is twice the sum of the series 1...(n-1)/2 and add on n+1/2 (the middle element).

Clearly you can generate any positive number that is less than this max as long as n>3.

So the problem then becomes finding the smallest n with a max greater than your target.

Algorithmically I'd go for:

Find (sqrt(4*s)-1) and round up to the next odd number. Call this M. This is an easy to work out value and will represent the lowest odd n that will work.

Check M-1 to see if its max sum is greater than s. If so then that your n is M-1. Otherwise your n is M.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases: s odd and s even.  When s is odd, you have the sequence:

1, 2, 3, ..., (s-1)/2, (s-1)/2, (s-1)/2-1, (s-1)/2-2, ..., 1

when n is even you have:

1, 2, 3, ..., s/2, s/2-1, s/2-2, ..., 1

Comment: that i know , but how to find value  of n.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all you answer me. I derived a simpler solution. The algorithm looks like-

```
First find what is the maximum  sum that can be made using n element-

if n=1 ->    1            sum=1;
if n=2 ->    1,1          sum=2;
if n=3 ->    1,2,1        sum=4;
if n=4 ->    1,2,2,1      sum=6;
if n=5 ->    1,2,3,2,1    sum=9;
if n=6 ->    1,2,3,3,2,1  sum=12;


So from observation it is clear that form any number,n  9<n<=12 can be 
made using  6 element, similarly number 
6<n<=9  can be made at using 5 element.
So it require only a binary search to find the number of
 element that make a particular number.
```

Comment: Is this implying that s is generally going to be small then? I wouldn't have thought this would be a great solution for values of s in the millions for example. If there is a constraint on s being small you should really include that kind of information in the original question since it makes a massive difference in what answer you will get. FWIW several of the answers above work on the above theory but without the lookup table and just using a bit of algebra to find the right value of n based on that maximum sum.

Comment: Its capable of handling a large number easily like if when n is only 100000 the maximum sum can be made to 2500050000 (a large number 32 bit number). And its also possible to handle larger number.And its running time is also good since no costly floating operation like sqrt() needed. It only require O(lgn) binary search.

Comment: I was more thinking that it might not necessarily be practical to have a lookup table. I'd imagine that your table would be about 8 meg in size which isn't much in the grand scheme of things but for one lookup object it feels quite a lot. Also I assume that this lookup table is hardcoded rather than being calculated on each use. I guess my only other comment is that I wouldn't say this was an algorithm, its just a lookup. These are often very good but you did tag the question as algorithm. :)

Comment: Yea, its not necessary if there is only single query but for large number of query say thousands/millions it's  required. And what else can i tag for this question??? ok, i can tag this as math, but it also need to generate a pattern, examine/observe the pattern for its correctness. is not it a type of algorithm???

Comment: I'd say it was maths really. If you'd wanted an algorithm to generate your lookup table then that's algorithm but I assume that is simple enough not to need one. And one step to look something up in the lookup table definitely doesn't feel like it should be called an algorithm.

Comment: Ok,i edited the tag. and tell me which answer should i accept.

Comment: @russell: How costly `sqrt()` is really? It's not more costly than `O(logn)`, and even more we only need `sqrt()` in integers, so `floor(sqrt())` actually.

Comment: A lookup table may not be useless though, if you have to do millions of lookups, as you say.